# How to type annotate a multi-level decorator

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to annotate an injector decorator that injects a value from a global dictionary as a keyword argument into the decorated function when the function is called.

Can anyone experienced with annotating decorators with parameters help me out?
Tried annotating but got stuck on the errors below:

```py
import functools
import inspect
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec


Type = TypeVar('Type')
Param = ParamSpec('Param')
_INSTANCES = {}


def make_injectable(instance_name: str, instance: object) -> None:
    _INSTANCES[instance_name] = instance


def inject(*instances: str) -> Callable[Param, Type]:

    def get_function_with_instances(fn: Callable[Param, Type]) -> Callable[Param, Type]:
        # This attribute is to easily access which arguments of fn are injectable
        fn._injectable_args = instances

        def handler(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> Type:
            new_kwargs: dict[str, Any] = dict(kwargs).copy()
            for instance in instances:
                if instance in new_kwargs:
                    continue
                if instance not in _INSTANCES:
                    raise ValueError(f"Instance {instance} was not initialized yet")
                new_kwargs[instance] = _INSTANCES[instance]
            return fn(*args, **new_kwargs)

        if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(fn):
            @functools.wraps(fn)
            async def wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> Callable[Param, Type]:
                return await handler(*args, **kwargs)

        else:
            @functools.wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> Callable[Param, Type]:
                return handler(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return get_function_with_instances
```

If I run mypy with these annotations I get these errors I cannot circumvent without creating new ones:

```
mypy injector.py --strict --warn-unreachable --allow-subclassing-any --ignore-missing-imports --show-error-codes --install-types --non-interactive

injector.py:33: error: "Callable[Param, Type]" has no attribute "_injectable_args"  [attr-defined]
injector.py:48: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "Callable[Param, Type]"  [no-any-return]
injector.py:48: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Type", expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
injector.py:53: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Type", expected "Callable[Param, Type]")  [return-value]
injector.py:55: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[Param, Coroutine[Any, Any, Callable[Param, Type]]]", expected "Callable[Param, Type]")  [return-value]
injector.py:57: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Callable[Param, Type]], Callable[Param, Type]]", expected "Callable[Param, Type]")  [return-value]
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The first `[attr-defined]` error is unavoidable IMO and should be simply explicitly ignored. There is no point in reinventing the wheel and defining your own special callable protocol with that special attribute.

The second and third errors with the codes `[no-any-return]`/`misc` I'll come back to later.

That fourth error with the `[return-value]` code comes up because the return annotation of your wrapper should be `T`, not `Callable[P, T]`. It is supposed to return whatever the decorated function returns after all.

The fifth error (also `[return-value]`) tells you that wrapper may be a coroutine that can be awaited to yield `T`, but you declared `get_function_with_instances` to return a callable that **returns** `T` (not a coroutine to await `T` from).

The very last `[return-value]` error comes up because `inject` returns a **decorator** that takes an argument of type `Callable[P, T]` and returns an object of that same type again. So the return annotation for `inject` should indeed be `Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]`, just as `mypy` says.

---

Now for the `[no-any-return]`/`misc` errors. This gets a bit confusing since your intention was to cover both the case of `fn` being a coroutine function and the case of it being a regular function.

You annotate `handler` to return `T` just like `fn`. But what that `T` is, is not further narrowed. The type guard given by `iscoroutinefunction` applies to `fn` and does not automatically extend to `handler`. From the point of view of the static type checker, `handler` returns *some object*. And that cannot be safely assumed to be awaitable. Therefore you cannot safely use it with `await` (the `[misc]` error).

Since the type checker doesn't even allow the `await` expression in that line, it obviously cannot verify that the returned value actually matches the annotation of `wrapper` (which should be `T` just like with the error mentioned earlier, but in this case it doesn't matter either way).

I am not 100 % sure about the root cause those two errors though.

---

If I were you, I would make my life a whole lot easier by not even inspecting the decorated function in the first place. The behavior of your decorator does not change. The only difference is that one call needs to be followed by an `await` to get the value. You can let the decorator be agnostic as to whether `fn` returns an awaitable or not and leave it up to the caller to handle it.

Here is my suggestion:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec


T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')
_INSTANCES = {}


def make_injectable(instance_name: str, instance: object) -> None:
    _INSTANCES[instance_name] = instance


def inject(*instances: str) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    def get_function_with_instances(fn: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        # This attribute is to easily access which arguments of fn are injectable
        fn._injectable_args = instances  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            for instance in instances:
                if instance in kwargs:
                    continue
                if instance not in _INSTANCES:
                    raise ValueError(f"Instance {instance} was not initialized yet")
                kwargs[instance] = _INSTANCES[instance]
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return get_function_with_instances
```

Here is quick test to show that the types are all correctly inferred:

```py
make_injectable("foo", object())


@inject("foo")
def f(**kwargs: object) -> int:
    print(kwargs)
    return 1


@inject("foo")
async def g(**kwargs: object) -> int:
    print(kwargs)
    return 2


async def main() -> tuple[int, int]:
    x = f()
    y = await g()
    return x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from asyncio import run
    print(run(main()))
```

Sample output:

```
{'foo': <object object at 0x7fe39fea0b20>}
{'foo': <object object at 0x7fe39fea0b20>}
(1, 2)
```

There are no complaints from `mypy --strict`. The way `main` is written, we can see that the return types are all inferred correctly, but if we wanted to check explicitly, we could add `reveal_type(f)` and `reveal_type(g)` at the end of the script. Then `mypy` would tell us:

```
Revealed type is "def (**kwargs: builtins.object) -> builtins.int"
Revealed type is "def (**kwargs: builtins.object) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, builtins.int]"
```

This is what we expected.

Comment: *The only difference is that one call needs to be followed by an await to get the value.* Wasn't it the case initially? `wrapper` in the original post is defined as `async def` in one of `if` branches, so `await`  was necessary anyway.

Comment: @SUTerliakov The actual function being wrapped may require the `await` at the end, if it returns a coroutine. But the wrapper **in this case** does not need to know about that because neither `wrapper` nor `handler` does anything with the returned value. Therefore my suggestion is to consciously get rid of the entire `async def` block and make the wrapper actually return whatever `fn` returns, whether that is an awaitable or any other type `T`. This circumvents the problem of trying to type the coroutine case distinctly. This also makes the entire code much simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extremely detailed answer @DaniilFajnberg!
Unfortunately within our code base the conversion from 2 wrapper functions to one didn't work, although mypy was satisfied.
I tried to annotate keeping the original skeleton but ran into cyclic issues again.
As this is not essential for us, we'll keep it untyped for the time being.